# Optimizing a query that selects from a select query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am trying to count all suspicious deposits from my app.

The query basically selects, counts and groups the results from an inner select query.

Using this query:

```
SELECT *, count(id) as repeated from (
    SELECT id, userAccount_id, `change_value_amount`,`change_value_currency_code`, JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$.depositId') as depositId From billing.transactions WHERE type_value = 'DEPOSIT_MADE'
) as q1 
where depositId is not null group by depositId having repeated > 1
```

Now, this query's execution time is 4-6 secs, which is really annoying.

I also tried creating a temporary table and do the outer where clause based from the temp table:

```
create temporary table if not exists susDeposit as (SELECT id, userAccount_id, `change_value_amount`,`change_value_currency_code`, JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$.depositId') as depositId From billing.transactions WHERE type_value = 'DEPOSIT_MADE');

select id, userAccount_id, change_value_amount, change_value_currency_code, depositId, count(*) as repeated  from susDeposit
where depositId is not null group by depositId having repeated > 1
```

in workbench, it executes at 1sec max.

but using pdo, it executes at 5secs, idk the reason why the execution time is different in workbench and pdo.

Code is:

```
$tempTable = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS susDeposit as (SELECT id, userAccount_id, `change_value_amount`,`change_value_currency_code`, JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$.depositId') as depositId From billing.transactions WHERE type_value = 'DEPOSIT_MADE');";
        $finalSelect = "SELECT id, userAccount_id, change_value_amount, change_value_currency_code, depositId, count(*) as repeated  from susDeposit
        where depositId is not null group by depositId having repeated > 1";

        $query = $this->pdo->query($tempTable);
        $query = $this->pdo->query($finalSelect);
        $query->execute();
        $r = $query->fetch();
```

Is there any way to optimize this query?

Comment: how many rows does this query return?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The inner select results to 161k+ rows.

Comment: and how many rows does workbench return?

Comment: The same, since they are using the same db connection.

Comment: double check that number

Comment: @YourCommonSense I see, in workbench, The reason why it's fast because the temporary table has already been created the second time I execute the query.

So my question, will fall, on how to optimize this query alone.

Comment: For that, you have to provide the usual info required for the sql optimization questions

Answer (score 0):

Start by not hiding columns that you need to test on inside JSON strings.

That is, when building the table, put `depositId` in its own column to help the Optimizer perform the query.

Once you have made that change and provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I'll help you make a suitable composite index (if needed).